# Modify shadow color of the ".hoverable" class in Materialize.css

Tags: css, hover, materialize, styling, box-shadow

I'm trying to change the shadow color of the .hoverable class in the Materialize.css framework, as the current color is not visible on dark backgrounds.

modifying box-shadow and text-shadow properties didn't worked.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col s12 m3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="image">
            <img src=# alt='image' />
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p class='card-name'>...</p>
                <p class='card-mail'>...</p>
                <p class='card-location'>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.card {
    background-image: linear-gradient(181.8322969733734deg, rgba(13, 33, 130,1) -2.5876288659793687%,rgba(56, 203, 229,1) 84.42268041237114%,rgba(57, 204, 230,1) 84.42268041237114%);
}

.card-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: send the css code plz?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 there is no futher css, as i am using only the materialize.min.css stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing the shadow color of a `.hoverable`, you should override a `box-shadow` for both `.card` and `.hoverable` class.

```
.card.hoverable {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 blue, 0 3px 1px -2px blue, 0 1px 5px 0 blue;
}
```

And to add your desired style for hover:

```
.card.hoverable:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px 0 blue, 2px 5px 3px -3px blue, 2px 5px 10px 0 blue;
}
```

You can use [cssmatic box-shadow generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) to create your desired box shadow.